# XML and XSLT and setting namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I need to add an xmlns to the root element in the output of this [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Transformations) transform. I've tried added `<xsl:attribute name="xmlns">` but it's disallowed.

Has anyone got any ideas how I could solve this?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:variable name="rootElement" select="name(*)"/>
            <xsl:element name="{$rootElement}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*"/>
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()"> 
        <xsl:copy> 
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply "add" a namespace, at least not in XSLT 1.0. Namespaces are fixed properties of the input nodes. You copy the node, you copy its namespace as well.

This means you'd have to create *new* nodes that are in the correct namespace. If you don't want a prefix, but a default namespace instead, the XSL stylesheet has to be in the same default namespace.

The following applies the default namespace to all element nodes and copies the rest:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://tempuri.org/some/namespace"
>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:element> 
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

turning

```
<bla bla="bla">
  <bla />
</bla>
```

to

```
<bla bla="bla" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/some/namespace">
  <bla></bla>
</bla>
```

Answer (score 4):

From [the XSLT 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl:element):

> The `xsl:element` element allows an element to be created with a computed name. The expanded-name of the element to be created is specified by a required `name` attribute and an optional `namespace` attribute.

So you need to declare the namespace prefix you wish to use on your `xsl:stylesheet` element, and then specify the namespace URI when you create the element.

To illustrate, the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:foo="http://example.com/foo">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="bar" namespace="http://example.com/foo">element</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo:bar xmlns:foo="http://example.com/foo">element</foo:bar>
```

Comment: The problem is how to make the nodes below use the same namespace.